# Losing ability to change properties when changing SourceObject of subform in Access 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, subform, beforeupdate

I have a subform that changes where it gets its data from based on user input by using the `Me.SubForm.SourceObject = Query.SomeQuery`. It seems that by doing this, I am losing the ability to set the `BeforeUpdate` property.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
Forms![PartsDatabase]![RepsSubform].Form![Pack Rank].BeforeUpdate = "=ToTracking()"
```

I have confirmed that this works before the `SubForm.SourceObject` is changed, but afterwards it throws the following error: RTE 2455 "You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property BeforeUpdate."

I was wondering if this is a known issue or if I just need to modify my code to adjust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting things muddled up here. You should never be changing Source Objects, rather you should be changing the Record Source. The code involved in the Form is Form level. If you wish to use the Before Update event, it belongs to the Form and not the Recordsource. So you always go to change the RecordSource.

You would use,

```
Forms!Parentform!SubForm.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT someFields FROM someTable;"
```

Or,

```
Forms!ParentForm!SubForm.Form.RecordSource = "yourCompiledQueryName"
```

Comment: Using `Forms![PartsDatabaseX]![RepsSubform].Form.RecordSource = "Query.SubFormFillerQry"` gives me the RTE 2455.

Comment: Is your Query actually named Query.SubFormFilterQuery? What is the Error Description. Have you spelt/used the right (sub)form name?

Comment: Ah, I thought I had to keep the "Query." on the front of the name. Unfortunately this has caused other problems with my code that was previously working - when I try to set properties on the subform when the record source is not set to what it is initially. These are of the form `Forms!ParentForm!SubForm!FieldName.Locked = True.

Comment: It looks like the subform is not changing its structure to match the query it's `rowsource` is changed to so the Fields aren't there to change

Comment: You can always use Aliases. For example, if this is one query SELECT yummy FROM foodTable; and another query is SELECT disgusting FROM garbageTable; You can make a common aliases like. SELECT yummy As newColumn FROM foodTable; and SELECT disgusting As newColumn FROM garbageTable; Then base your form control's source to this newColumn, so even if you change the recordsource they will be able to look up to the right column.